# Help with probability problem involving participants as a variable

Tags: probability

(1) Suppose you have a deck of 30 cards, with 4 cards being red hearts.
(2) Suppose you are a member of a group of 20 people participating in the sorting.
(3) You want to know what is the probability of you getting one of the 4 red hearts, while at the same time you want to know the probability of your best friend getting other of the 4 red hearts.

My problem is that I don't know how to take into account that the 30 cards need to be given to only 20 people.

Answer (score 0):

There is a $4/30$ chance you will get one of the red cards.  Given that you so get one, there is a $3/29$ chance your friend gets one of the remaining red cards.

Multiply these two probabilities.